# Floated Element applies background to other div as well

Tags: css, css-float

Ok So the title is kind've confusing but this is my set up.

```
<div id="leftPanel">
   // blah blah
</div>

<div id="rightPanel">
   // blah blah
</div>
```

I am floating the rightPanel next to the Left Panel. When I apply a background CSS to rightPanel it flows through and also applies to leftPanel. Why is this? Is it because I haven't defined widths? When I do define widths, it behaves as if float-left wasn't in place.

```
#leftPanel {
      float: left;                      
  }

  #rightPanel {       
      background: blue;       
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right you have an `div` with no defined `width` this is going to stretch 100% of the window width (by default).

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/27Zem/)

### HTML:

```
<div id="rightPanel">
   // blah blah
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#rightPanel {
    background: blue;
}
```

---

So what's going to happen when you float a `div` in front of it? The floated `div` is going to allow the next `div` to sit on the same line as it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/27Zem/1/)

### HTML:

```
<div id="leftPanel">// blah blah</div>
<div id="rightPanel">// blah blah</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#leftPanel {
    float: left;
}
#rightPanel {
    background: blue;
}
```

---

Here you can see that the floated `div` is just sitting there and the background on the other `div` is not 100% any more due to the width we have now given it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/27Zem/2/)

### HTML:

```
<div id="leftPanel">// blah blah</div>
<div id="rightPanel">// blah blah</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#leftPanel {
    float: left;
}
#rightPanel {
    background: blue;
    width: 32px;
}
```

I would recommend taking a look at [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530755%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find more out about how floats works.